# Binary tree variable type issue

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I'm having trouble with a method I wrote to insert string words into a binary tree. The below code is the method in question. Basically, the word is inserted if it is not yet in the tree (as a `BinaryTreeNode`), and if it is in the tree, its frequency (count variable within `BinaryTreeNode`) is increased by one. My problem is with the temporary variable `searchWord`. Defining it as a `String` creates a type mismatch and a statement that says `getFrequency()` is not defined for type `String`. The generic type `T` is only there as a placeholder - it too does not work. What should it therefore be defined as?

buildBinaryTree method:

```
public static void buildBinaryTree(String word) {
    //if word is already in tree
    if(wordTree.contains(word)) {
        //find existing word node
        T searchWord = wordTree.find(word);  //problem here

        //increment frequency by 1
        searchWord.setFrequency(searchWord.getFrequency() + 1);
    } else {
        //add word to tree
        System.out.println(word);
        wordTree.addElement(word);
    }
}
```

BinaryTreeNode constructor:

```
/**
 * Creates a new tree node with the specified data.
 * @param obj the element that will become a part of the new tree node
 */
BinaryTreeNode(T obj) {
   element = obj;
   left = null;
   right = null;
   frequency = 1;
}
```

Frequency get/set methods:

```
/**
 * Gets the frequency.
 * @return the frequency
 */
public int getFrequency() {
   return frequency;
}

/**
 * Sets the frequency.
 * @param frequency the frequency to set
 */
public void setFrequency(int frequency) {
   this.frequency = frequency;
}
```

Comment: Where are getFrequency method defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking in chat, you should define a class that has both a `String` and `int` that you use as the type to place in the binary tree, to replace the type variable `T`. Then, you can define methods such as `getString()` to return the `String`, `incrementFrequency()` to add one to the frequency, etc. When you get an object out of the binary tree, it will be the right type to call these methods.

Comment: After doing this, I receive the message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to BinaryTreeNode`. I should mention that `find()` returns an object of type `T`.

Comment: `wordTree` is a binary tree. I'm not sure what you mean by "post the code", since it's only a one line definition. Do you need any specific methods from the binary tree class?

Comment: Why doesn't the `find` method return a `BinaryTreeNode`?

Comment: The binary tree class was given to us, I didn't write it. In the comments, it states "Returns a reference to the specified target element if it is found in the binary tree.  Throws a NoSuchElementException if the specified target element is not found in this tree."

Comment: What type of element does it return? Are you trying to call a method in a class you defined on a generic object?

Comment: `find()` returns an element of type `T`. I tried casting `searchWord` to `BinaryTreeNode`, but after the first occurrence of a word already in the tree, I get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to BinaryTreeNode`. I'm sorry, but I'm new to this, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "calling a method in a class I defined on a generic object".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9887/discussion-between-mteckert-and-lollercopter)